# Parsing out data from json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, for-loop

Wrecking my head today trying to find out how to loop through and log out the name of each object.

Here is the JSON response:

```
    {
        "placeListings": {
            "OBJ1": {
                "Active": true,
                "Name": "place 1"
            },
            "OBJ2": {
                "Active": true,
                "Name": "place 2"
            },
            "OBJ3": {
                "Active": true,
                "Name": "place 3"
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to parse out the "Name" part in a for loop

```
 for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    console.log("NAME: " + res.placeListings.OBJ1.Name);
                }
```

But I don't know how to iterate through OBJ1/OBJ2/OBJ3 etc..

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `placeListings` is an object, not an array.
So you need to use the [`Object.keys`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/object/keys) method to get the object's keys

```js
const source = {
  placeListings: {
    OBJ1: {
      Active: true,
      Name: 'place 1'
    },
    OBJ2: {
      Active: true,
      Name: 'place 2'
    },
    OBJ3: {
      Active: true,
      Name: 'place 3'
    }
  }
}

const keys = Object.keys(source.placeListings)
console.log(keys)

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log(source.placeListings[keys[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this with a single line of code by using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

Demo **:**

```js
const res = {
  "placeListings": {
    "OBJ1": {
      "Active": true,
      "Name": "place 1"
    },
    "OBJ2": {
      "Active": true,
      "Name": "place 2"
    },
    "OBJ3": {
      "Active": true,
      "Name": "place 3"
    }
  }
};

Object.keys(res.placeListings).forEach(key => console.log(res.placeListings[key].Name));
```